# Disabling (Apache) Basic Authentication for OPTIONS requests

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, authentication, http-basic-authentication

I have Apache basic authentication enabled on a test server and it works great:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "testing"
AuthUserFile /home/www/.htpasswd
Require user MyUser

deny from all
```

But it is also trying to authenticate requests sent via the OPTIONS method. Which is a problem because the CORS specification says that you should `Exclude user credentials` - https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0

How do I disable authentication for requests coming in with the OPTIONS method?

(Similar to this for Tomcat: [Disable authentication for OPTIONS requests in Tomcat](https://serverfault.com/questions/725988/disable-authentication-for-options-requests-in-tomcat) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps use an Apache expression (Apache 2.4+) to only apply the HTTP Basic Auth directives when the request method is *not* "OPTIONS".

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} != 'OPTIONS'">
# Authentication directives...
</If>
```

Reference:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

> ```
> deny from all
> ```

You shouldn't need to use this (Apache 2.2) directive with your Basic Auth directives.

Comment: Excellent, worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<RequireAny>
     Require method OPTIONS
     Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

With Apache Module mod_authz_core
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html

ps. Above works for me with

```
AuthName "Dostęp wymaga autoryzacji. Nieautoryzowany dostęp jest logowany"
 AuthUserFile /home/website/.htpasswd
 AuthType basic



Order Deny,Allow
 Satisfy any
 Deny from all
 Require valid-user
 // this is for use with mod_setenvif.c
 Allow from env=noauth
```